# AWK include empty/null entries in delimited text file

Tags: awk

I have tried batch '`for loops`', and Linux AWK. Both seem to have the same issue, where they ignore empty entries in a tab delimited file. I try to print the 32nd column, but because some previous entries have nothing between two tabs, it creates problems.

*Is there a workaround for this? Or any other language you recommend for this?*

```
Col1            Col3    Col4
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
```

Comment: post the actual input fragment

Comment: For some reason, the tabs are showing as spaces, but imaging there are 2 tabs between Column 1 and 3 on the first row. Everything else is 1 tab. Try to print column 3

Comment: you wrote *print the 32nd column*, post the **actual** few lines containing all columns and expected result for those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell `awk` that your field separator is a tab using the `-F` option. Example to print the third column with your example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
Col1            Col3    Col4
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
$ awk -F '      ' '{print $3}' foo.txt
Col3
Col3
```

Comment: Rather define `awk -F'\t' ...`